# Typescript: How to use a union in an interface correctly?

Tags: typescript

This should have been simple but, when defining an interface with `options` type:

```
  options:
     Array<{
        title?: string;
        options: Option[];
      }>
    | Option[];
```

I'm using map function to loop over the array, something like this:

```
  {options.map((option) => (
              <SelectPrimitive.Group key={option.title}>
```

Then I won't be able to access option.title, ts will say this title property doesn't exist. But the moment I remove the second part of the union:

```
options:
     Array<{
        title?: string;
        options: Option[];
      }>
```

It will work. Why doesn't ts understand that it's a union type, and instead it selects the second part of the union?

Comment: Assuming your `Option` interface also has a property called `title`, this should work. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=20#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgeTBgQiTjgG8BYAKHPOJgBtgB+ALjgGcYpkBzANy16cAG6YmAV2CcpSANZIIAdyTCaAX1q0W8CERJIu7EaICCUKJgCeAHmp1R9Riw7deAjc-oHipEwJDUgBtAF1vZ00APjNyAB8g-yRwuABeOHCNMz8jLgA6AFtMMAAKXNJ06LhsAIgWfKYIfnLgpHzXYABKLqA)

Comment: `Why doesn't ts understand that it's a union type, and instead it selects the second part of the union?` That's not how it works. A union is simply telling the compiler "it can be this interface OR that interface". It can't decide on its own which type it is, so before using it you will have to cast it to the preferred type/interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually understands that's a union type.

When using a union type `A | B` it means that the object can be of type `A` or  type `B`. `TS` will do type checking taking into account both `A` and `B`. Common properties will work, but if a property is only on one type you need to `narrow` the type.

That's where your error is coming from.

Comment: Thank you very much now I understand, what I don't know how to do is how to check the type of the prop in real time, maybe I should open a new question about it

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question about "how to do is how to check the type of the prop in real time", you can simply check with a if statement if the object `option` in the map, is an instance of Option. You could also just check the type of the first element in `options` before your map.

Example 1

```
options.map((option) => (
    if (option instanceof Option) {
        <SelectPrimitive.Group key={option.title}>
    }

...
```

Example 2

```
if (options.length !== 0 && options[0] instanceof Option) {
    options.map((option) => (
          <SelectPrimitive.Group key={option.title}>
          ...
}
```